# Как собрать информацию из нескольких узлов mqtt Node-Red?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Всем привет!
Существующая схема в Node-Red: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Функция `db_query` описана следующим образом и заносит в БД только значения одного узла:

```
var newMsg = {payload : msg.payload};
newMsg.topic ="INSERT INTO `m2m`.`sens1` (`TEMP`) VALUES ("+newMsg.payload+")";
return newMsg;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как написать сбор данных (функция collect_data) от узлов в несколько переменных для передачи их в функцию db_query и создания одного SQL INSERT запроса в БД.

Таблица в БД в которую заносят данные:

```
select * from sens1;
+----+------+-------+-------+-----+---------------------+
| id | TEMP | HUMID | PRESS | AIR | date                |
+----+------+-------+-------+-----+---------------------+
|  1 | 41.2 |     0 |     0 |   0 | 2016-11-15 22:08:54 |
+----+------+-------+-------+-----+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Максим, немного непонятны критерии сбора данных от сенсоров.

Допустим, что они более-менее синхронизованы и шлют данные примерно в одно время и сохранение всех четырёх параметров является обязательным условием. Тогда можно собирать все данные в одно сообщение стандартной нодой 'join'. Вот так:

[image: пример с нодой join]

В этом случае сообщение на выходе join будет когда на вход придут 4 сообщения и они объединятся в msg.payload c которым уже можно работать:

`{
   "humidity":"1518169847055",
   "temperature":"1518169848336",
   "gas":"1518169849289",
   "preassure":"1518169850240"
}`